# How to edit a current goggle script to only return details from a particular folders in a shared drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, directory, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a script (thankyou Cooper) that I'm trying to use to generate a list of all folders and files from within one particular folder in a shared drive, however, the script is returning the following error:

```
Exception: Argument too large: value
gff @ Folder Listing.gs:67
(anonymous) @ Folder Listing.gs:72
gff @ Folder Listing.gs:68
(anonymous) @ Folder Listing.gs:72
gff @ Folder Listing.gs:68
(anonymous) @ Folder Listing.gs:72
gff @ Folder Listing.gs:68
(anonymous) @ Folder Listing.gs:72
gff @ Folder Listing.gs:68
(anonymous) @ Folder Listing.gs:72
```

I'm assuming the problem is the script is grabbing all folders and files within the shared drive file and it's far too large to run the script, so I'm trying to reduce the source size by targeting a particular folder (or just returning the folder names and not worry about files at all).

What can I change on this script reduce the size issue?

```
function sharedDriveTrees() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("blah");//need to change the ssid for the output spreadsheet
  const r = Drive.Drives.list();
  const drives = JSON.parse(r).items;
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter((sh, i) => i < drives.length).filter(e => e);
  var trees = [];
  drives.forEach((obj, i) => {
    obj["title"] = obj.name;
    let ob =JSON.parse(Drive.Files.get(obj.id,{ supportsAllDrives: true, supportsTeamDrives: true }));
    obj["alternateLink"] = ob.alternateLink;
    Logger.log('Drive Title: %s Time: %s', obj.title, Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss"));
    shts[i].setName(`${obj.title}\n${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")}`);
    let tree = [];
    CacheService.getScriptCache().put("tree", JSON.stringify(tree), 60);
    level = 1;
    gff(obj)
    tree = JSON.parse(CacheService.getScriptCache().get("tree"));
    let l = tree.reduce((a, c) => {
      if (c.length > a) {
        a = c.length;
      }
      return a;
    }, 0);
    tree.forEach((a, j) => {
      if ((l - a.length) > 0) {
        let arr = [...Array.from(new Array(l - a.length).keys(), x => "")];
        tree[j] = a.concat(arr);
      }
    });
    trees.push(tree);
    const sh = shts[i];
    sh.clearContents();
    sh.getRange(1, 1, tree.length, tree[0].length).setValues(tree);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  });
}

level = 1;
function gff(fobj) {
  //Logger.log('Drive Title: %s', fobj.title);
  const r = Drive.Children.list(fobj.id);
  const fldrMime = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
  let tree = JSON.parse(CacheService.getScriptCache().get("tree"));
  let files = [];
  let subfolders = [];
  fobj["level"] = level;
  let children = JSON.parse(r).items;
  children.forEach((obj, i) => {
    let o = JSON.parse(Drive.Files.get(obj.id, { supportsAllDrives: true, supportsTeamDrives: true }));
    o["level"] = level;
    if (o.mimeType == fldrMime) {
      subfolders.push(o);
    } else {
      files.push(o);
    }
  });
  //Logger.log('level: %s', level);
  let arr1 = [...Array.from(new Array(level).keys(), x => { if (x < (level - 1)) { return '' } else { return `=HYPERLINK("${fobj.alternateLink}","${fobj.title}")` } })];
  //Logger.log('arr1: %s', JSON.stringify(arr1));
  tree.push(arr1)
  if (files && files.length > 0) {
    files.forEach(obj => {
      let arr2 = [...Array.from(new Array(level + 1).keys(), x => { if (x < (level)) { return '' } else { return `=HYPERLINK("${obj.alternateLink}","${obj.title}")` } })];
      //Logger.log('arr2: %s', JSON.stringify(arr2));
      tree.push(arr2)
    })
  }
  CacheService.getScriptCache().put("tree", JSON.stringify(tree), 60);
  subfolders.forEach(obj => {
    level++;
    obj.level = level;
    CacheService.getScriptCache().put("tree", JSON.stringify(tree), 60);
    gff(obj);
    tree = JSON.parse(CacheService.getScriptCache().get("tree"))
  });
  level--;
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Edit:

After checking the affected line I found out that the issue is happening at `CacheService.getScriptCache().put("tree", JSON.stringify(tree), 60)`. The [Cache Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#putkey,-value,-expirationinseconds) explains that the limit for the second parameter `value` is 100KB. The original script creator was using the CacheService as kind of a global variable to save every iteration of the loop as it kept adding levels to the tree. Since your folder structure is pretty large it grew beyond the 100KB limit.

As far as I can tell there's no way to raise this limit so I rewrote a few lines to pass the object to the `gff()` function instead of using the cache.

I kept the hyperlinks, but I also added a couple commented lines that you can switch to just return folder names as you requested. You can find them at `let arr1 =` and `let arr2 =`. You can switch between them to see if there's a performance improvement. You could also just change those lines in the original code that uses the cache, but you may still eventually run into the limit:

```js
function folderTrees() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<Your spreadsheet id>");//need to change the ssid for the output spreadsheet
  const f = Drive.Files.get("<Folder ID>", { supportsAllDrives: true, supportsTeamDrives: true });
  const obj = JSON.parse(f);
  const sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var trees = [];
 
  Logger.log('Folder Title: %s Time: %s', obj.title, Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss"));
  sh.setName(`${obj.title}\n${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")}`);
  let tree = [];
  level = 1;
  tree = gff(obj, tree)
  let l = tree.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (c.length > a) {
      a = c.length;
    }
    return a;
  }, 0);
  tree.forEach((a, j) => {
    if ((l - a.length) > 0) {
      let arr = [...Array.from(new Array(l - a.length).keys(), x => "")];
      tree[j] = a.concat(arr);
    }
  });
  trees.push(tree);
  
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1, 1, tree.length, tree[0].length).setValues(tree);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

}

level = 1;
function gff(fobj, treeobj) {
  const r = Drive.Children.list(fobj.id);
  const fldrMime = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
  let tree = treeobj;
  let files = [];
  let subfolders = [];
  fobj["level"] = level;
  let children = JSON.parse(r).items;
  children.forEach((obj, i) => {
    let o = JSON.parse(Drive.Files.get(obj.id, { supportsAllDrives: true, supportsTeamDrives: true }));
    o["level"] = level;
    if (o.mimeType == fldrMime) {
      subfolders.push(o);
    } else {
      files.push(o);
    }
  });
  //first line adds the hyperlinks and the second one returns only text
  let arr1 = [...Array.from(new Array(level).keys(), x => { if (x < (level - 1)) { return '' } else { return `=HYPERLINK("${fobj.alternateLink}","${fobj.title}")` } })];
  //let arr1 = [...Array.from(new Array(level).keys(), x => { if (x < (level - 1)) { return '' } else { return  fobj.title } })];
  tree.push(arr1)
  if (files && files.length > 0) {
    files.forEach(obj => {
      //first line adds the hyperlinks and the second one returns only text
      let arr2 = [...Array.from(new Array(level + 1).keys(), x => { if (x < (level)) { return '' } else { return `=HYPERLINK("${obj.alternateLink}","${obj.title}")` } })];
      //let arr2 = [...Array.from(new Array(level + 1).keys(), x => { if (x < (level)) { return '' } else { return obj.title } })];
      tree.push(arr2)
    })
  }
  
  subfolders.forEach(obj => {
    level++;
    obj.level = level;
    tree = gff(obj, tree);
  });
  level--;
  return tree;
}
```

And here's the output:
[image]

A few things to note:

- You'll need to get the folder ID to plug into the `f` variable.
- The original script looped through all the shared Drives and wrote each one's tree to a different sheet within your spreadsheet. Since you only seemed to want a single folder's tree now it just writes to the first sheet in the file.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, I should have included the error details. I ran your script this morning and I'm still getting the same errors, can we edit the script to just return folder names?  
Exception: Argument too large: value
gff @ Folder Listing.gs:67
(anonymous) @ Folder Listing.gs:72
gff @ Folder Listing.gs:68
(anonymous) @ Folder Listing.gs:72
gff @ Folder Listing.gs:68
(anonymous) @ Folder Listing.gs:72
gff @ Folder Listing.gs:68
(anonymous) @ Folder Listing.gs:72
gff @ Folder Listing.gs:68
(anonymous) @ Folder Listing.gs:72

Comment: I've edited the question too.

Comment: It turns out that the issue was in the CacheService. I edited my post with an explanation and added new code that doesn't use the cache anymore. I also added a couple lines that you can switch between to change whether or not you want links. I didn't have a chance to test with a large folder structure so please give it a try in your environment and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel - yep the size is a major problem. Can we take files out of the equation and just focus on folders only - this is the problem I received after I applied your edit: 12:09:48 PM Error 
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.get failed with error: Internal Error
(anonymous) @ Folder Listing.gs:43
gff @ Folder Listing.gs:42
(anonymous) @ Folder Listing.gs:67
gff @ Folder Listing.gs:64
(anonymous) @ Folder Listing.gs:67
gff @ Folder Listing.gs:64
folderTrees @ Folder Listing.gs:12

Comment: I tested your edit on a smaller individual folder and it works perfectly, so I'm thinking if we just grab folders (and possibly just the first two levels) - would that work?

Comment: Let me check. Do you have an idea of what the hierarchy looks like? Is it wide or deep?

Comment: Mostly deep - I run an accounting firm, so we keep everything we need for that specific year etc. so we have Clients > Name > Year and then in that folder, we have all the information we need for that year - it could vary from 1 document to hundreds depending on the size of the client. We have the information for that year split up in numerous folders for understanding purposes.